# Why will Latex in R not display this figure?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am trying to display a figure in one of my documents using Latex in RStudio. For some reason when I compile the PDF, the figure does not display. Can anyone help me with this?

Latex Code:

```
    \subsection{Plots}
\begin{figure}
<<eval=False>>=
x=matrix(NA,16,30)
x
x[,1]=0.01

calc.x=function(r,X)r*X*(1-X)

l= seq(.25,4.0,.25)
time= seq(2,30,1)
length(l)
length(time)
par(mfrow=c(4,4))
for (i in 1:16) {
  for (t in 1:29) {
    x[i,t+1]=calc.x(l[i],x[i,t])
  }
  for (i in seq_along(l)) {
    plot(1:30, x[i,], main =bquote(lambda == .(l[i])),xlab="Day", ylab="Population")
    abline(h = 1, lty = 2, col='grey')
  }
}
@
\caption{kill me}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code chunk has `eval=FALSE`.  If that's not the issue, then please post a reproducible example.

Comment: and also need `fig=TRUE`